# Issue retrieving current_user in Devise with different model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have got Devise setup in my rails app with my model called auth_user instead of user. I have tried accessing the currently logged in user's email address (a field called email) for me to use in a query against an Employee model like so

```
@employee = Employee.find_by_Email(current_auth_user.email)
```

but get the error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Paul

** EDIT ********

Fix as suggested by @theButler in the comments. Resolution was to add

```
before_filter :authenticate_auth_user!
```

To the top of the class.

Comment: Could you post your AuthUser class definition?

Comment: two things, do you do a check first to see `if auth_user_signed_in?`, and second, in `find_by_Email`, shouldn't email be lowercased?

Comment: Good call @theButler, added before_filter :authenticate_auth_user! to the top of the controller.